# What's the meaning of char zero (0) in Java?

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java string replace and the NUL (NULL, ASCII 0) character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523284/java-string-replace-and-the-nul-null-ascii-0-character)

I'm doing some String algorithms in Java, and i noticed that wherever i include a char with the value of 0 (zero) it marks the end of the String. Like this:

```
String aString = "I'm a String";
char[] aStringArray = aString.toCharArray();
aStringArray[1] = 0;
System.out.println(new String(aStringArray)); //It outputs "I"
```

What's the reason/cause of this behaviour?

Comment: Null Character: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The character `'\0'` is the null character. It's a control character, and it *does not* terminate the string, that's not how strings work in Java (that's how they work in C, though.)

Answer (score 3):

For some additional insight, add the following to you code:

```
 System.out.println(new String(aStringArray).length());
 for (Byte b : new String(aStringArray).getBytes()) {
     System.out.print("["+b+"]"); 
 }
```

Your rendering system (console or output window) is not displaying everything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you have posted your actual code. When using the [String(byte[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D%29) constructor the actual length of the string is dependent on the contents of the array.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Where are they using the "String(byte[])" constructor?