# String Basic Concept Regarding Null values

Tags: java, string

What is the difference between a String `"\0"` and a String `""` ?
Both are null but there must be some difference, so what is it?

Comment: What do *you* think the difference is?

Comment: *"Basically both are null"* ... do you know what [`null`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java) is?

Comment: Java strings are not null terminated unlike languages such as C++

Answer (score 5):

The first one is a String containing a single character, whose value is 0.

The second one is a String containing 0 character.

None of them are null. Objects can't be null. References to objects can be.

Comment: from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753576/whats-the-meaning-of-char-zero-0-in-java , The character '\0' is the null character. It's a control character. so is your statement that first string value is 0. Is that correct ? Though i am not sure what null character means .

Comment: the first String's value is not 0. The single character contained in the first string has the value 0. `char` is a numeric type, whose values go from 0 to 2^16 - 1. The "null character" is the character whose value is 0. The 'a' character is the character whose value is 97.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet. Got you partially. Its kind of  (char)(0) . But as its a control character(non printable), what can be practical use of it. I understand \t is also non printable character but when i print it , it  displays tab space but i am not sure how \0 helps practically ?

Comment: You can imagine using it as a separator in a network protocol, or when you send messages to a hardware device that gives it some special meaning. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character

Answer (score 1):

Both of these strings are not null, because there's a special `null` value in Java which means absence of any object. The "" string is actually empty, and the string with single `\0` character is not empty. Its length is 1, for example. And they are not equal to each other.

Unlike C/C++ `\0` symbol is perfectly valid in Java strings.

Answer (score 0):

None of them are `null`,  first String contains "\0" and second string is an empty string . If you invoke `length` method on firstString you will get `1` and `0` on second string

Answer (score 0):

```
    String n1="\0";
    String n2="";
    System.out.println("\n"+n1.length()+"\n"+n2.length());
```

Output:

1

0

n1 has single character where n2 is an empty string.