# Why append the null character "\0" when looking for a headSet in a SortedSet?

Tags: java, sortedset

What does this idiom means? A java string concatenated with "\0" (e.g. "Japan\0")? As in

```
SortedSet<String> countryHeadSet 
    = countrySet.headSet("Japan\0");
```

What does the string `"Japan\0"` mean in the call?  Would it make any difference if the programmer writes just

```
countryHeadSet 
    = countrySet.headSet("Japan");
```

Comment: Have you looked at this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753576/whats-the-meaning-of-char-zero-0-in-java

Comment: the `'\0'` char is `null` char

Comment: Actually, it's the character `NUL`, as a `char`, known as the "null character", but not `null`, which is a Java keyword and doesn't apply to primitive types. I bring it up because the words are so similar, but the meanings so different. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character https://unicode-table.com/en/ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-EscapeSequence

Comment: Hi, Thanks for all the help.  I have found the answer and provided it below.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the answer.  Thanks for all the ideas.

One of the use of the idiom of a string + `"\0"`, especially when you see it
with a range-view operation of a `SortedSet`, is to use it to find the 
**successor** of the string.

Such a successor is needed because those range-view operation (`subSet()`
, `headSet()`, and `tailSet()`) provide *half-open* intervals, and you 
may need the successor of a string to construct a *closed* interval.  This is explained in the [Java Doc of Sorted Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html)

> Several methods return subsets with restricted ranges. Such ranges are
>   *half-open*, that is, they include their low endpoint but not their high
>   endpoint (where applicable). If you need a closed range (which
>   includes both endpoints), and the element type allows for calculation
>   of the successor of a given value, merely request the subrange from
>   lowEndpoint to successor(highEndpoint). For example, suppose that s is
>   a sorted set of strings. The following idiom obtains a view containing
>   all of the strings in s from low to high, inclusive:
>
> SortedSet sub = s.subSet(low, high+"\0");

In other words, the difference between the two calls below:

```
countrySet.headSet("Japan\0");
countrySet.headSet("Japan")
```

is that the first one would get all the strings in `countrySet` 
in the range from the beginning of the set, up to and *including*
the string `"Japan"` (i.e. the range is a *closed* interval); while
the second would get all the strings in the range from the 
beginning of the set, up to *but not including*
the string `"Japan"` (i.e. the range is a *half-open* interval).

I am including a test program of my own to demonstrate the use of the 
idiom:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class StringPlusNull {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> countryList 
            = Arrays.asList("U.S.", "U.K.", "China", "Japan", "Korea");
        SortedSet<String> countrySet
            = new TreeSet<>(countryList);

        String toElement = "Japan";
        SortedSet<String> countryHeadSet 
            = countrySet.headSet(toElement);
        System.out.format("There are %d countries in the "
                + "(half-open) headset [, %s): %s%n"
                , countryHeadSet.size(), toElement, countryHeadSet);

        toElement = "Japan\0";
        countryHeadSet 
            = countrySet.headSet(toElement);
        System.out.format("There are %d countries in the "
                + "(half-open) headset [, %s): %s%n"
                , countryHeadSet.size(), toElement, countryHeadSet);
    }

}
```

The output would be:

```
There are 1 countries in the (half-open) headset [, Japan): [China]
There are 2 countries in the (half-open) headset [, Japan ): [China, Japan]
```