# How do you get rid of null in a String in Java?

Tags: java, string, io

I have this string "nullRobert Luongo 431-232-1233 Canada"

and I'd like to get rid of the null character. I don't know how it got there, but I would like to get rid of it.

Comment: Never look for bandaids. Fix things at their source. It will save you a lot of headache.

Comment: This has already been answered here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523284/java-string-replace-and-the-nul-null-ascii-0-character

Comment: what is your expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that you get it because you did something like this:

```
String s = null;
.
.
.
s+="Robert Luongo 431-232-1233 Canada"; //mind the +=
```

One way to correctly do it is by:

```
String s= "";
```

Comment: Oh, that's probably what I did.

Answer (score 3):

You're concatenating a String that is null -- don't do that. Initialize the String at least with ""

So rather than

```
String myString;
```

When you do this and later do:

```
myString += "something";
```

you'll get `nullsomething

So instead assign an empty String to the String of interest when you declare it.

```
String myString = "";
```

Comment: That is just one out of many different reasons why the OP could end up with this String...!?

Comment: @jangroth: true, but the most common that I've seen.

Comment: it is too much for me that someone questioned you @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: @KickButtowski: sorry that makes no sense. jan groth's comments were spot on.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels it does not matter if it makes sense or not, but I sitll cannot consume someone questioned you :)

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Recommended

I would suggest you to look into the issue from where the string is contains 'null' and fix it at the source rather than using hacks.

Option 2: Not recommended

But still if you want to replace the null from it then you can use the following. But it is not recommended as it can replace a proper word containing 'null' in it and make the string junk.

The following replaces the first instance of 'null' with empty String.

```
string.replace("null", "");
```

You can also replace all the instances of 'null' with empty String using replaceAll.

```
string.replaceAll("null", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
String stringWithoutNull = stringWithNull.replaceAll("null", "");
```